# Using python's easy_install through a SOCKS5 proxy

Tags: python, proxy, easy-install, socks

Well, the title is pretty explanatory by itself. I need to install python stuff using easy_install, but I need easy_install to connect through a SOCKS5 proxy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When i need to protect my connection, i'm using [tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/). It act as a transparent layer for network connection. Create a configuration file named `tsocks.conf`:

```
server = 127.0.0.1
server_type = 5
server_port = 1080
```

Then you can use it like this (sudo is needed only for easy_install):

```
TSOCKS_CONF_FILE=tsocks.conf tsocks sudo easy_install -U docutils
```

A side note, i'm mostly using ssh with socks proxy feature too (this example will connect to the ssh of myserver.com, and create a local socks proxy server listening on the port 1080):

```
ssh -D 1080 myserver.com
```

Comment: Thanks tito, I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: BTW, I'm also using the ssh -D option too. Actually, the socks proxy I'm trying to use with easy_install is precisely an ssh connection like this one.